# Loading drafts works onload but not when triggered by a button

Tags: google-apps-script

I intend to write a simple Google Apps Script mail merge app, as a bound script, starting from a draft mail from the user. I open a sidebar with a dropdown to select the drafts. When I fetch the drafts onLoad, it works fine, but when I trigger the fetching with a button, the sidebar is cleared without any error being shown in the console.

I stripped the code to a bare minimum to show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <form>
      <div class="block">
      <div class="inline form-group">
        <label for="draft">Choose</label>
        <select id="draft">
          <option disabled selected>One moment please ...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block" id="button-bar">
        <button id="reload">reload</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      getDrafts();
      $('#reload').click(getDrafts);
    });

    function getDrafts() {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(loadDrafts)
        .withFailureHandler(showError)
        .getDraftMessages();
    }

    function loadDrafts(drafts) {
      $('#draft').find('option').remove();
      for (var i = 0; i < drafts.length; i++) {
        $('#draft').append('<option value="' + drafts[i].id + '">' + drafts[i].subject + '</option>');
      }
    }

    function showError(msg, element) {
      var div = $('<div id="error" class="error">' + msg + '</div>');
      $(element).after(div);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The back end javascript (the .gs file) is:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menu = [{
    name: 'Mailmerge tests',
    functionName: 'mailMerge'
  }, ];
  ss.addMenu('MM experiment', menu);
}

mailMerge = function() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MailMergeUI').setTitle('Mail merge');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function getDraftMessages() {
  try {
    draftMessages = GmailApp.getDraftMessages();
    drafts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < draftMessages.length; i++) {
      drafts.push({
        'id': draftMessages[i].getId(),
        'subject': draftMessages[i].getSubject()
      })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw (err);
  }
  Logger.log("Returning: ");
  Logger.log(drafts);
  return drafts;
}
```

The Logger logs the correct drafts, but the .withSuccessHandler(loadDrafts) in the sidebar is not executed; instead, the sidebar freezes.

In the Chrome developer tools I cannot find the scripts to debug them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the html, I think this happens because the button submits the form. If you make this suggested edit to your client side js, I hope it will fix it.

```
$(function() {
  $('#reload').click(getDrafts).click();
});

function getDrafts(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(loadDrafts)
    .withFailureHandler(showError)
    .getDraftMessages();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint!!! Removing the <form> tag did the job as well. Learned something again!